# Android Adwords integration

Tags: android, google-ads-api

I am trying to integrate adwords in an Android application to track conversion events. Can you please clarify, how to test my app. After integrating and running the app I can see the following log where the event is to be triggered :

09-27 18:55:44.948 25792-3609/xxx I/GoogleConversionReporter: Pinging: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/....

09-27 18:55:45.138 25792-3609/xxx I/GoogleConversionReporter: Receive response code 200

But the conversion label in Google Adwords dashboard is not updated. Will the label only get updated if the app is installed via an adword click? Is there no way to check the dashboard gets updated & thus verify end to end flow before going live?

Comment: give it some time .... check after a while.

Comment: @SohailZahid It has been around 3 hours already. What is the normal delay seen?

Comment: check tommorow.